# How do I get rid of connection refused error in hadoop?

Tags: java, hadoop

When I try to run hadoop command

> vinit@ubuntu:~/hadoop-1.0.4$ bin/hadoop dfs -ls

I get following things as output.

> 13/04/17 06:26:37 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:9010. Already tried 0 time(s).
>   13/04/17 06:26:38 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:9010. Already tried 1 time(s).
>   Bad connection to FS. command aborted. exception: Call to localhost/127.0.0.1:9010 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused

I am new to hadoop and even Java.Please Help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if your HDFS processes are running? Run 'jps' command to check the running java processes.

You shoudl have at least 'Namenode' and 'Datanode' processes running. Please check and let me know.

Cheers
Rags

Comment: vinit@ubuntu:~/hadoop-1.0.4$ jps
'6932 TaskTracker
12630 Jps
6379 DataNode
6705 JobTracker
6611 SecondaryNameNode'

Comment: I do not see "Namenode" process running. Have you formatted HDFS before you started the cluster? Without Namenode running the HDFS can not respond.

Comment: Yeah. There was an error in my core-site.xml. As soon as my namenode started, HDFS started responding. Can you suggest any link online to learn hadoop from basics!

Comment: Online documentation is the best place but it is too much to digest at once at the beginning. For an organized learning I suggest to start with "Hadoop in action" and them move on to "Hadoop the definite Guide". Happy learning!

Answer (score 0):

I have struggled two days and the night between to find out the answer to this problem.

In my case( and I'm sure this is the problem in most cases ) had to create the hadoop temporary folder by hand and add them to the hdfs-site.xml !

```
<property>

<name>dfs.data.dir</name>

<value>/home/stefan/Downloads/hadoop-2.7.1/tmp/dfs/name/data</value>

<final>true</final> 

</property> 

<property> 

<name>dfs.name.dir</name>

<value>/home/stefan/Downloads/hadoop-2.7.1/tmp/dfs/name</value> 

<final>true</final> 

</property>
```

I hope this helps you guys not to go through the same hell as me.

Besides that

```
chown user_name hadoop_folder hadoop_temp_folder
chmod 755 hadoop_folder hadoop_temp_folder
```